# Setting up sublimetext 3 as git commit text editor

Tags: git, sublimetext3

I'm having trouble setting up sublime as my git commit message editor.

Using:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl"
```

Error:
error: cannot run subl: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'subl'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

subl work perfectly otherwise.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can solve this by putting in a full path

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w"
```

Source: [OS X Command Line](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html)

**EDIT**: *If the name of the app is not `Sublime Text.app` you will want to replace that with the correct name.*

Comment: Your answer is correct but it didn't solve my problem, I must have a wider configuration issue.

Comment: No, I had to use this `git config --global core.editor '/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'`

Comment: This is not the right answer. The second one should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, corrected the command line options which I misses first time round.

Answer (score 134):

For what it's worth, here's how I solved it:

1) Run in Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

This adds a `subl` alias to `/usr/local/bin/` pointing to Sublime Text 3 app’s binary file. Now running `subl` in Terminal will launch Sublime Text 3 app.

2) Run in Terminal:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

This adds `editor = subl -n -w` to the `[core]` section of the `~/.gitconfig` file. Now running `git commit` in Terminal will launch Sublime Text 3 app (`subl`) in a new window (`-n`), and the command line will wait (`-w`) until the commit message is saved *and* closed.

*Image of final workflow added in response to clarifying question in comments below:*

[image]

Official Sublime Text 3 doc: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

Comment: what it means `and the command line will wait (-w) until the commit message is saved.` 
I write comment in sublime open file and press W but do not ends. how to do it?

Comment: @diEcho, just save and close the Sublime window containing your commit message, and switch to Terminal again if you aren't switched there automatically. The `-w` at the end of the string in the Terminal command is an optional flag to trigger a 'wait'—you don't need to type it again.

Comment: when I am about to close it ask to save on some location. where do I save this file

Comment: @diEcho, it shouldn't ask where to save. The file should automatically be named `COMMIT_EDITMSG` and its location should automatically be `.git` (visible on Mac by command-clicking the filename in the Sublime window's title bar). All that should be necessary (once steps 1 & 2 above are complete) is to run `git commit` in Terminal, write your commit message in the file that auto-launches in Sublime, save that Sublime file, and close that Sublime window. Your file in Sublime was automatically created, yes? And your window in Sublime was automatically launched?

Comment: @diEcho, I've added an image above hopefully to help.

Comment: I have performed steps 1 and 2, but when I save and exit, the terminal just hangs...Why could that be?

Comment: I have the same issue as @layser.  git just sites there and does nothing after saving and closing sublimeText3.

Comment: The difference that I've noticed is whether sublime is already running or not. If it's not running, it's possible that several windows got spawned (from a previous session), and you have to close all of them to get it to save. If it is already running, it creates a new process with one window, and behaves how you'd expect.

Answer (score 16):

**Sublime Text 2**

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

**Sublime Text 3** *( Tested this on my Windows 10 MS Surface Pro 3 )*

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -n -w"
```

You can also add following line to your .gitconfig file

```
[core]
 editor = "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -n -w"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Add the -n option if you want it to open in a new window!

Answer (score 8):

I found out that I receive messages like:

`subl -n -w: subl: command not found.`

`error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'`

`error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl'`

even though Sublime works well and can be launched from Terminal.

To fix it, run the following in Terminal:

```
git config --global core.editor " 'XXXXX' -n -w"
```

while 'XXXXX' is the path which Sublime is launched from.

It could be `/usr/bin/subl` as Pranav Misra mentioned, or  `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`, or whatever you put in the symlink you have created.

Comment: Yup, I was struggling with escape sequences and this solved my problem. I don't know whether the space character right after the `"` is necessary, and I don't want to right now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to the community, and apologize if the answer is not in the proper format.
For me the following things worked for Sublime 3 `git config --global core.editor " '/usr/bin/subl' -n -w"` 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

To add sublime Text as the default text editor  , first create a symlink :

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Also , make it the default editor for any time when input is asked by

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

Finally ,

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these answers, but nothing worked. ~/.gitconfig showed that sublime was set, but git wouldn't pick up the change.  In the end, I restarted my macbook, and that did it. srsly.

`git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`