# git commit error relevant to ST3

Tags: git, sublimetext3

i have created a new local repository and initialize it, then i define ST3 as default editor

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

and when i commit i got this error

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Skipping command-line '"C:\Users\Sony\bin\..\usr\bin\bash.exe"'
('C:\Users\Sony\bin\..\usr\bin\bash.exe' not found)
Need a valid command-line; Edit the string recources accordingly
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38811187/6309):

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```

This is [also documented by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor-1).

It will work better when done from a CMD (instead of a bash session) because of the way the quotes (simple and double) are interpreted.

Comment: did it before still sme probleme

Comment: @IlyesGhomrani Are you doing it in a CMD sesion, or a bash session? What is your current version of Git?

Comment: bash session, version : 2.16.2

Comment: @IlyesGhomrani Can you try the same git config command I mention in the answer from a CMD session? As well as the next git commit?